# How to make sum of Row which are flitered with specific column values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, sum, row

i have a dataframe like below.
 Trying to sum Week 7 and Week 8 
 SalesQuantity values for all the regarding productCodes[1-317], and update their  week 7 rows Sales Quantity as a new value. And deleting their Week 8 rows from Dataframe.

Week column range is [7-26] and all of the weeks include [1-317] product code 
 cause of the original data is before group by [Week,ProductCode]

```
 Week  ProductCode  SalesQuantity
  7            1      49.285714
  7            2      36.714286
  7            3      33.285714
  7            4      36.857143
  7            5      42.714286
 ...          ...            ...
  8            3      61.000000
 26          314       4.285714
 26          315       3.571429
 26          316       6.142857
 26          317       3.285714
```

Example Result : From the above table, adding week 7+8 SalesQuantities for product code 3: 61.000+33.285714= 94.285.714‬ new SalesQuantity updated value for week 7 is founded for ProductCode 3.
After that, need delete Week 8 row for ProductCode 3.

How to automate it for all of the ProductCode[1-317]?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `groupby()' method:

```
sumSales = data[['productCode', 'SalesQuality']].groupby('ProductCode').sum()
```

This creates a new DataFrame, with the sum of SalesQuality, indexed with the product code. The `data[['productCode', 'SalesQuality']]` part creates a sub-selection of the original data frame, otherwise the weeks also get summed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I mean now  in dataframe Week is like this [7,8,11,12,21,22,23,25,26]. I want to reduce it 4 value like summing Sales Quantity Week[7+8] onto Week[7] and Week[11+12] onto Week[11], Week[21,22,23] onto Week[21] finally Week[25+26] onto Week[25]. In the last dataframe I just only need Week 7,8,21,25 updated rows and others are deleted.Is it possible because i am quite beginner:)